# Where can I add global function to be used in minitest-rails-capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I want below function to be called in **every** feature test, like **global/public function** (*must be available in all feature test*):

**Since most of the test requires login first.**

```
def feature_login(username, password)
  scenario 'user sign in with valid data' do
    within 'form' do
      fill_in 'username',    with: username
      fill_in 'password', with: password
      click_button 'continue'
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to put the above code in **test_helper.rb**, but I got:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `scenario'
```

It seems like the syntax is different (not like in usual feature test).

In my Login feature test:

```
  require "test_helper"

  feature "Login" do
    before do
      visit root_path
    end

    scenario 'user sign in with valid data' do
      feature_login('admin', 'my_pass') # so I can simply call like this.    
      page.current_path.must_equal '/en/home'
    end
  end
```

**I want to call the public function, like feature_login('admin', 'my_pass') 
.**

How can I accomplish that one?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Oh!, I figured it out.

Simply by removing the **scenario** block.

In my test/test_helper.rb.

```
  def feature_login(username, password)
      within 'form' do
        fill_in 'username',    with: username
        fill_in 'password', with: password
        click_button 'continue'
      end
  end
```